# What did Jake Lo mean?

Tags: dialogue, rapid-fire

One scene from *Rapid Fire* (1992) contains [the following exchange](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105219/characters/nm0000855):

> Agent Frank Stuart: I want you to know, Jake, that I'm the only one who did this to myself, and to you. I want you to know that I take responsibility for my personal actions.
>
> Jake Lo: **This isn't EST, Frank.**

What does Jake's response mean?

I remember him saying that and no one could figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EST or Erhard Seminars Training was a well known self help seminar in the 1970s and early 1980s.

[From wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhard_Seminars_Training)

> Erhard Seminars Training (marketed as est, though often encountered as EST or Est) was an organization, founded by Werner Erhard in 1971, that offered a two-weekend (6-day, 60-hour) course known officially as "The est Standard Training". The seminar aimed to "transform one's ability to experience living so that the situations one had been trying to change or had been putting up with clear up just in the process of life itself".[2][3] **An est website claims that the training "brought to the forefront the ideas of transformation, personal responsibility, accountability, and possibility"**.

Comment: Thank you!  This has haunted me forever!